# Wordpress: Query shows posts when logged in, but not when logged out. Not set to private.

Tags: php, wordpress

I am completely baffled. I'm managing someone else's Wordpress install, but this is a new problem, which never happened previously.

I have a page which displays a query of a custom post type. The query works, and displays the custom posts. When I am logged out, the query generates no results. The posts are definitely set to "public" and not Private. They are definitely published, not drafts. They do show up in other queries on other pages, but on this one page, no luck. I can't for the life of me fix it! Here is the code for the page:

```
<?php /*
      Template Name: Classes Template
 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

   <?php 

$wmodulepage = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wmodulepage', true);

?>

<div style="padding-top:10px; background:#fff;">

 <div class="pageInfo">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="eight columns pageTitle">

                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            </div>

            <div class="eight columns breadcrumb">

               <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display')) {
                        bcn_display();
                        }?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

  <ul id="reset">

  <li><a class="reset" href="#" data-filter=".one-third">reset</a></li>


</ul>


   <div class="pageContentWrapper">

        <div style="padding-top:10px; background: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/newBg.jpg)  no-repeat fixed center;">

        <div class="container">


            <center><hr><a class="button-big lightblue rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/education">ALL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button-big purple rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/class/pre-k">PRE-K</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button-big taupe rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/class/k-2">K-2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!--<a class="button-big teal rounded3" href="../class/summer-camps">SUMMER CAMPS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--><a class="button-big brown rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/class/elementary">ELEMENTARY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button-big purple rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/class/middle-school">MIDDLE SCHOOL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button-big teal rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/class/high-school">HIGH SCHOOL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button-big teal rounded3" href="http://millmountain.org/class/adult">ADULTS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><hr></center>



                  <ul class="classesPost dd_classes_widget widget clearfix ">



                    <?php

global $paged;

$arguments = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_classes',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private' ),
    'meta_key' => 'class-order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);


// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post_classes' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
);

// The Query
$my_Classes_Query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $my_Classes_Query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_Classes_Query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_Classes_Query->the_post();
?>

                       <li <?php post_class('one-third column'); ?>>

                              <?php 

$thumbimg = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'thumbimg', true);


?>

                            <div class="wrapper">


                                <?php if( $thumbimg) { ?>

                                  <div class="postThumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbimg; ?>" alt="" /></a></div>

      <?php } ?>    






                            <div class="postDetails">

                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="postTitle"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                 <a class="button-small red rounded99" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('MORE INFO', 'localization'); ?></a>

                            </div>

                            </div>

                        </li>

<?
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();



?>













                 </ul>


<h1 style="text-align: center;">Supporters</h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">The following organizations have given grants that support the MMT Conservatory programs:</p>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gallery  columns="7" ids="2511,2512,2513,2514,2515,2516,2517"]' ); ?><br><br>


                   <?php
                            kriesi_pagination();

                            dd_restore_query();
?>                  



        </div>

    </div>

 <?php if ( $wmodulepage == 'yes') { ?>

<div class="widgetModuleWrapper">

    <ul class="widgetModule container clearfix">

          <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Widgetized Module")) ; ?>

    </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</div>
        <?php } ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I included the whole template in case I might be overlooking something outside of the query and loop that is causing the problem. Can anyone help? I'm so confused. I have rewritten the query and the loop, with no success. I even completely replaced this page with a different template for a different custom post type, changed the post type in the query, and got the same result. It seems to somehow be related to the posts themselves, rather than the query, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot from here.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you might be wrapping your `register_post_type` in a `is_admin` or something, might want to check your functions.php file.

Comment: Try enabling debugging and disable any caching plugins

Comment: Here is an update - I figured something out - this is related to the page slug I think. I changed the URL from /education/ to /education-2/ and it works fine. Also, oddly, the Wordpress Admin Bar does not appear on this page, but does on all others, even with the different slug. These are all new problems, that have suddenly appeared, after working fine for several years!

Comment: I might have fixed it by removing this:

Comment: <?php
                            kriesi_pagination();

                            dd_restore_query();
?>